# Basics to how a distributed, consistent key-value storage system return the latest key when dealing with concurrent requests?

Tags: concurrency, distributed-system, system-design, distributed-caching, quorum

I am getting up to speed on distributed systems (studying for an upcoming interview), and specifically on the basics for how a distributed system works for a distributed, consistent key-value storage system managed in memory.

My specific questions I am stuck on that I would love just a high level answer on if it's no trouble:

**#1**
Let's say we have 5 servers that are responsible to act as readers, and I have one writer. When I write the value 'foo' to the key 'k1', I understand it has to propagate to all of those servers so they all store the value 'foo' for the key k1. Is this correct, or does the writer only write to the majority (quorum) for this to work?

**#2**
After #1 above takes place, let's say concurrently a read comes in for k1, and a write comes in to replace 'foo' with 'bar', however not all of the servers are updated with 'bar. This means some are 'foo' and some are 'bar'. If I had lots of concurrent reads, it's conceivable some would return 'foo' and some 'bar' since it's not updated everywhere yet.

When we're talking about *eventual consistency*, this is expected, but if we're talking about *strong consistency*, how do you avoid #2 above? I keep seeing content about quorum and timestamps but on a high level, is there some sort of intermediary that sorts out what the correct value is? Just wanted to get a basic idea first before I dive in more.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In doing more research, I found that "consensus algorithms" such as Paxos or Raft is the correct solution here. The idea is that your nodes need to arrive at a consensus of what the value is. If you read up on Paxos or Raft you'll learn everything you need to - it's quite complex to explain here, but there are videos/resources out there that cover this well.

Another thing I found helpful was learning more about Dynamo and DynamoDB. They handle the subject as well, although not strongly consistent/distributed.

Hope this helps someone, and message me if you'd like more details!

Answer (score 0):

Read the `CAP theorem` will help you solve your problem. You are looking for consistence and network partition in this question, so you have to sacrifice the availability. The system needs to block and wait until all nodes finish writing. In other word, the change can not be read before all nodes have updated it.

> In theoretical computer science, the CAP theorem, also named Brewer's
> theorem after computer scientist Eric Brewer, states that any
> distributed data store can only provide two of the following three
> guarantees:
>
> 1. Consistency Every read receives the most recent write or an error.
> 2. Availability Every request receives a (non-error) response, without
>    the guarantee that it contains the most recent write.
> 3. Partition tolerance The system continues to operate despite an arbitrary number
>    of messages being dropped (or delayed) by the network between nodes.